# when you are developing an Android application ,if you want download data asynchronously from web server ,how do you solve?

Tags: android, web-services, asynchronous

Now I am developing an Android application ,and I want to download data asynchronously from web server with WebService ,how I solve it ???

Comment: are you using any frameworks/libraries? Usually asynctask is the way to go for communications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this. One of the most popular is using the `AsyncTask` class provided by the Android API.

You can read more about `AsyncTask` [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

There is also a whole page dedicated to Threads and Processes in the official developer guide, which is available [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).